# Delete row if two patterns are found in the same line

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I'd like to delete a line from a text file (`input.txt`) if two patterns (`string1`and `string2`) are found on the **same** row, using `sed`.

I'm trying: 
`sed -i "/\b\(string1\|string2\)\b/d" input.txt`, but this is deleting rows containing `string1` OR `string2`.

Comment: Will the strings always be in the same order? I mean `string1...string2` or can you also have `string2...string1`?

Comment: In my specific case, yes, they are in the same order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed -i "/string1.*string2\|string2.*string1/d" input.txt
```

This will delete any line where string1 appears before string2, OR string2 appears before string1.  Both strings have to be on the line, in either order, for the line to be deleted.

Comment: Note that it if `string1` is `foobar` and `string2` is `barbaz`, it will not delete a line containing `foobarbaz`.

Comment: Note that it won't work if there are byte sequences not forming valid chars inbetween `string1` and `string2` in the input. You may want to add a `LC_ALL=C` to guard against that (for instance if the locale is UTF-8 based and there's a chance that `input.txt` be in a different  encoding). That would have a side effect of potentially changing the language of error messages though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yep, your sed version is better in that situation...actually, better overall.  (although i'd use `;` as a statement separator rather than two `-e` scripts. same result, less typing).  and your awk and perl versions are equivalent to your sed version.

Comment: It's true it won't make a difference with GNU sed, and GNU sed is required for that particular usage of `-i` anyway, but on U&L I prefer to avoid GNUisms if possible. For instance, that way here, to adapt to FreeBSD sed, you just need to change the `-i` syntax (`-i '' -e...`) and the rest will still work. As per the current version of POSIX, `b;/string2...` is meant to branch to the `;/string2...` label (which means GNU sed is not compliant), future versions will leave the behaviour unspecified ([on my request](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=945)) (which will make GNU sed compliant).

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -ie '/string1/!b' -e '/string2/d' file.txt
```

That deletes lines that contain both `string1` and `string2` regardless of the order (may even overlap as when looking for `foobar` in `barbaz` in a line containing `foobarbaz`).

`-i` above is a GNU extension. Another GNU-specific solution¹:

```
awk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '!(/string1/ && /string2/)' file.txt
```

Portably, you'd probably use `perl` here:

```
perl -ni -e 'print unless /string1/ && /string2/'
```

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.put unless .match(/ foobar / & / barbaz / ) ;'   file
```

OR

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.put unless grep({ / foobar / & / barbaz / }, $_ ) ;'   file
```

Above are two general ways to accomplish the OP's task using Raku. Note `grep` in Raku is similar to `grep` in Perl, except a comma is required after the block. You can also use the `.grep` method call instead, and not have to worry about writing `$_` inside the parentheses.

Either code example above will delete lines that contain two strings, *regardless of order AND regardless if the strings overlap.* For example:

Sample Input:

```
1  foo
2  bar
3  baz
4  foobar
5  foobaz
6  barbaz
7  foobar foobaz
8  foobaz barbaz
9  foobar barbaz
10 foobar foobaz barbaz
11 foobaz barbaz foobar
12 barbaz foobar foobaz
13 foobarbaz
```

Sample Output (either code example above):

```
1  foo
2  bar
3  baz
4  foobar
5  foobaz
6  barbaz
7  foobar foobaz
8  foobaz barbaz
```

The above code deletes lines 9-through-13, including line 13 `foobarbaz` which contains overlapping string1 and string2. If you need to delete strings that appear in a defined order (and without overlap), Raku can do that too:

```
~$ raku -ne '.put unless m/foobar .* barbaz/;'  file
```

Above removes lines 9 and 10: `foobar barbaz` and `foobar foobaz barbaz`.

---

<sup>Note, using Raku regexes you ***can*** detect two strings that overlap, with the `:overlap` (or `:ov`) parameter/adverb. See first link below.</sup>

---

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Overlap
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org